# how to convert CSS and HTML to PDF

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Ok, I'm by no means a programmer, but I'm fluent at HTML and CSS, and know some javascript even thou I work as a graphic designer.

I was looking to make a small web app, so the client could make their own business cards, without relying on me every time a new employee arrives.

The procedure would be simple, the client would just have to type the name and the job position of the employee, and by submitting it would generate a PDF with the new card using a preestablished design by me.

I think I can do the part of inserting the data in the card with CSS, HTML, and a little Javascript or PHP perhaps?

But how can I convert the page in a printable PDF?

Comment: Sooo many duplicates on Google and in the right hand column :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought my case might be especific enough, my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

There is [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for generating PDF from HTML + CSS.

> **TCPDF** is a PHP class for generating PDF documents without requiring external extensions. TCPDF Supports UTF-8, Unicode, RTL languages, XHTML, Javascript, digital signatures, barcodes and much more.